# How to add a string from a file into matching files

Tags: shell

I am trying to go through a list of workstations, and add data to their corresponding individual files. I have already made the individual files, but now I need help using sed or something else to replace text in the individual XML files:

For example:

workstation_list.txt has the following lines:

```
workstation1
workstation1.domain.com
127.0.0.1
00:00:00:00:00:00

workstation2
workstation2.domain.com
127.0.0.2
11:11:11:11:11:11
```

---

I have two files: workstation1 and workstation2 with the following XML:

```
< HOST_NAME >workstation3< /HOST_NAME >
< HOST_FQDN >workstation3.domain.com< /HOST_FQDN >
< IP >127.0.0.0< /IP >
< MAC >33:33:33:33:33:33< /MAC >
```

I can do a "while read line do" without a problem, but I've never used more than one variable.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole task can be accomplished with a single call to [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk):

```
awk -v RS='\n\n' '{               
  print "< HOST_NAME >" $1 "< /HOST_NAME >" > $1
  print "< HOST_FQDN >" $2 "< /HOST_FQDN >" > $1
  print "< IP >"        $3 "< /IP >"        > $1
  print "< MAC >"       $4 "< /MAC >"       > $1

  close($1)
}' file
```

Given your sample input it creates two files as follows:

**workstation1**:

```
< HOST_NAME >workstation1< /HOST_NAME >
< HOST_FQDN >workstation1.domain.com< /HOST_FQDN >
< IP >127.0.0.1< /IP >
< MAC >00:00:00:00:00:00< /MAC >
```

**workstation2**:

```
< HOST_NAME >workstation2< /HOST_NAME >
< HOST_FQDN >workstation2.domain.com< /HOST_FQDN >
< IP >127.0.0.2< /IP >
< MAC >11:11:11:11:11:11< /MAC >
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have two more questions: 

1.)Would I add the cat workstationlist.txt before the syntax? 

2.) what if I had 100 workstations? could I loop through each one?

Comment: @Joseph no, you don't need `cat` here. just change `file` with `workstation_list.txt` and you're good to go